# Captioning all frames of a gif

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I have a simple bash script to caption still images (jpg, png...) but it completely fails when given an **animated** gif. The error is `convert: unable to write pixel cache '/tmp/magick-[random chars]': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/WritePixelCachePixels/5854.` There are many questions [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088597/adding-text-on-animated-gif-with-imagemagick-and-php) [to](https://gist.github.com/damncabbage/4774574) [mine](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#label), however they use specific coordinates to determine where the text should be placed (at least, I think). My script creates a dynamically sized caption area for the text to be written to. The image is appended to the bottom of the caption area (or the caption area is prepended to the top of the image, however you want to think about it.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
caption=$2
output=$3
wd=`convert $input -format "%w" info:`
convert  \( -size ${wd}x -background white -gravity north -fill black -font FuturaBT-ExtraBlackCondensed -pointsize $(($wd/17)) \
caption:"$caption" \) \
$input \
-append $output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this in Imagemagick.

```
convert anim.gif -coalesce \
-gravity north -background white \
-splice 0x18 -font Arial -pointsize 12 -annotate +0+0 'THIS IS A TEST OF CAPTIONING TEXT' \
-layers Optimize anim3.gif
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick you will need to create a text image from your caption and then use -layers composite to apply it to your animation.

Input GIF Animation:

[image]

Imagemagick 6 Unix Syntax:

```
convert  \( anim.gif -coalesce \) null: \( -size 100x -background white -gravity north -fill black caption:"THIS IS A TEST OF CAPTIONING TEXT ON AN ANIMATION" \) -compose over -layers composite -layers optimize anim2.gif
```

[image]

For Windows, remove the \s

For Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, this overlays the caption on top of the gif, and my script intentionally creates a space **above the image** for writing the text to.

Comment: That was not clear to me. Sorry.